# Come on people! what am I?

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, lateral-thinking

You are in a store when out of nowhere you hear a voice. It asks.

> what am I?

It follows the question with a story.

> I asked a lady before and she said “I think you are a banana?”
>
> then I asked a man who came around and said “I am pretty sure you are a banana?”
>
> then I asked a young teen and he told me “I don’t know, you might be a banana?”

**What am I? And why are people so unsure?**

Comment: Is the fact that declarative sentences are being ended with questions marks relevant?

Comment: No I just used the question marks to signify low confidence or unsureness in their answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe...

> You are indeed a banana. However people are not so sure about it, because bananas don't usually talk.

Or maybe...

> You're a worker in a banana costume. The costume is very well made; it's totally obvious that you "are" a banana. So obvious that others don't understand why do you even ask (they think it may be a trick question).

Comment: Great job! The first on is correct!

Answer (score 5):

I think you are:

> A Plantain - you look like a banana, but you’re not! This is why people are so unsure?

Comment: Never thought about that. Great answer but not what I am looking. It is really simple and doesn’t require any background knowledge.